# Should I dispatch an action for navigation in React/Redux

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I'm using React with Redux and thunks. I want to use `browserHistory.push`, but not sure where should I call this function. Let's say, we have a component, it has a simple button. When you click the button, I want to call the `browserHistory.push` method. My understanding of redux is, that I should dispatch an action (`{type: 'NAVIGATE'}`) and create a thunk, where I would call the `browswerHistory.push` method. The component would only request the navigation and the thunk would actually handle the request.

However, I've heard different opinions, like actions in Redux should be used only when you update the store. If you are not modifying the store, then no need to dispatch an action.

What is the best solution to this problem?

Comment: You may take a look at react-router-redux (https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/tree/master/packages/react-router-redux), it's essentially what you are asking for. If you are not already using react-router, then you aren't gonna need it. Don't over complicate stuffs!

Comment: I'm already using `react-router`, I want to redirect from code, not use `Link` etc.

Comment: @Tr1et, react-router-redux is not there any more.  At https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/tree/master/packages

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `push` method from `react-router-redux` and bind it as an action creator just like any other redux action.

```
import React from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { push } from 'react-router-redux'

function YourComponent({ redirectTo }) {
  return (
    <div>
      ...
      <button onClick={() => redirectTo('/nextRoute')}>
        Click-me
      </button>
    </div>
  )
}

export default connect(
  undefined,
  { redirectTo: push }
)(YourComponent)
```

Comment: Could you please add the middleware registration code?

Comment: Thank you for this answer, it is helping me, but does not really answer the question. Does this mean, that I should create a redux action for this (resp. use the one form `react-router-redux`)?

Comment: You don't need a redux action. The `push` method is the action already.

Comment: Yep, I understand. I could use the `push` method. This is what I am asking. Should I use something like `push` or should I call `browserHistory.push` directly from the component?

Comment: I'd call `push` directly. In this case you don't need `browserHistory.push`.